# flutter: space between horizontal listView items

Tags: flutter

i'm trying to implement horizontal list view in flutter and  it's working good but products are too attached to each others, is there a way to put space between them ?
thanks in advance

```html
 Row(
  children: <Widget>[

                 Expanded(
          child: SizedBox(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: httpService.getProducts(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.data == null) {
            return Container(
              child: Center(
                child: Text('Loading...'),
              ),
            );
          } 
          else if (snapshot.data.length == 0){
            return Container(
              child: Center(
                child: Center(
                  child: Text('No offers'),
                ),
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return ListView.builder(
          
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
           
              itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => (AlAinPdtItem(
                  title: snapshot.data[i].title,
                  imgUrl: snapshot.data[i].imgUrl,
                  price: snapshot.data[i].price,
                  pdt2: snapshot.data[i])),
            );
          }
        },
                 )))])
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 24):

To add space between the items, these are 2 solutions:

- **First (recommended)**, replace your `ListView.builder` by a `ListView.separated`, and add the tag `separatorBuilder`.

Example, to add a space between each item:

```dart
return ListView.separated(
   separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return SizedBox(height: 3);
   },
   scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
   shrinkWrap: true,
   itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
   itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => (AlAinPdtItem(
      title: snapshot.data[i].title,
      imgUrl: snapshot.data[i].imgUrl,
      price: snapshot.data[i].price,
      pdt2: snapshot.data[i])),
);
```

You can replace the SizedBox by a Divider, or any widget you need.
The advantage of this solution is that it will add a separator **between** each item, and won't add an extra one at the end.

- **Second option**, if you really need to keep the `ListView.builder`, wrap your widget `AlAinPdtItem` in a Padding:

```dart
return ListView.builder(
   scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
   shrinkWrap: true,
   itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
   itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => (Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 10),
      child: AlAinPdtItem(
         title: snapshot.data[i].title,
         imgUrl: snapshot.data[i].imgUrl,
         price: snapshot.data[i].price,
         pdt2: snapshot.data[i])),
      ),
);
```

The drawback of this is that the Padding will be added on **each** item, which means that the last item will have an extra space (10px in this case) afterwards.

Comment: thanks for ur answer, i tried both of them but still products attached to each others and there are no spaces between them

Comment: I tried both, it works well. Do you have a minimal sample of code to reproduce?

Comment: i added the same exact code in ur answer but as if nothing changes :\

Comment: I can't help if I can't reproduce your issue. Provide a sample of code to reproduce. For instance I don't have the AlAinPdtItem class, or I don't see where httpService is defined.

Answer (score 1):

Or if you don't want to use `ListView.separated()`, you can add your own spacings like this:

```dart
ListView(
  children: myListTiles.expand((tile) => [tile, SizedBox(height: 12)]).toList()..removeLast()
)
```

(Edit: The `..removeLast()` only works if your list is non-empty, so maybe not the perfect solution)